# Why does nmap show port 25 as open? Server's firewall should block port 25

Tags: port, firewalld, nmap

`nmap` 7.70 executed remotely shows the server's port 25 as open. However, the firewall on my VPS server only opens ssh, http and https services.

On the laptop:

```
nmap x.x.x.x

Not shown: 996 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
25/tcp  open   smtp
80/tcp  open   http
443/tcp closed https
```

On the server:

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all

public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client http https
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

I made sure the firewall is reloaded and test after a reboot.
How could the port 25 possibly be showed as open? I do not have any mail server installed. Postfix service has been removed.

```
# systemctl list-units --type=service --state=running

auditd.service           loaded active running Security Auditing Service
chronyd.service          loaded active running NTP client/server
crond.service            loaded active running Command Scheduler
dbus.service             loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus
firewalld.service        loaded active running firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
getty@tty1.service       loaded active running Getty on tty1
httpd.service            loaded active running The Apache HTTP Server
mariadb.service          loaded active running MariaDB 10.3.13 database server
network.service          loaded active running LSB: Bring up/down networking
rh-php71-php-fpm.service loaded active running The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
rsyslog.service          loaded active running System Logging Service
sshd.service             loaded active running OpenSSH server daemon
systemd-journald.service loaded active running Journal Service
systemd-logind.service   loaded active running Login Service
systemd-udevd.service    loaded active running udev Kernel Device Manager

# netstat -tulpn

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2857/php-fpm: maste
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2973/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      2872/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      6620/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2973/sshd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           2789/dhclient
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           2019/chronyd
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                2019/chronyd

# lsof -i -n -P | grep LISTEN

php-fpm  2857    root    7u  IPv4  20425      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
mysqld   2872   mysql   19u  IPv6  20474      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
php-fpm  2879  apache    0u  IPv4  20425      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm  2880  apache    0u  IPv4  20425      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm  2881  apache    0u  IPv4  20425      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm  2882  apache    0u  IPv4  20425      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm  2883  apache    0u  IPv4  20425      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
sshd     2973    root    3u  IPv4  21087      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd     2973    root    4u  IPv6  21106      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
httpd    6620    root    4u  IPv6 114083      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    6621  apache    4u  IPv6 114083      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    6622  apache    4u  IPv6 114083      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    6623  apache    4u  IPv6 114083      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    6624  apache    4u  IPv6 114083      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    6625  apache    4u  IPv6 114083      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    6626  apache    4u  IPv6 114083      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    6627  apache    4u  IPv6 114083      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Are you sure it is the correct server you are scanning? Sometimes some routing etc. takes place and redirects ports "on the way". We had a similar question here some time ago. Which server answers when you `telnet 25` to the IP?

Comment: @Lenniey telnet opens a session for port 25 on the server. Weird... I tried port 21 just to make sure and it is closed. It is the correct IP.

Comment: What's the answer on `telnet 25` of your server? You can capture the packets using tcpdump or wireshark, for example. Do you have any other zones configured in firewalld?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to surely know is to get a set of simultaneous network captures on source (machine running nmap) and destination (server). Then look for:

- Do you see SYN packets destined to port 25 on the destination machine's capture?
- Do you see responses (SYN,ACK) for the above SYNs **on the destination machine's capture**?

If the answers are NO/NO or YES/NO (really unlikely, but possible) this is a false positive.

If you have a false positive and would like to know more, open then the source capture and look at the SYN,ACK coming theoretically from the server. Got it? Now in the IP layer check for the TTL value, got it?

Now on the same capture look for the SYN,ACK coming from the server for an open port test, e.g. 22/TCP. Look for the TTL value. It's likely they won't match.

If the TTL for the SYN,ACK on 22/TCP is something lower but close to 64, 128 or 255 the difference from the number to the closest of those is the number of hops from the source to the server. Now compare to the number in the SYN,ACK for 25/TCP and you might see a completely different number (e.g. 58 for 22/TCP and 254 for 25/TCP).

If the SYN,ACK for 25/TCP is close but lower to 64, 128 or 255 calculate the number of hops and you'll know where is the device that's responding to your SYNs (probably a network firewall doing application inspection).

If the SYN,ACK for 25/TCP is exactly 64, 128 or 255 changes are your gateway is doing this or even a local security software in your box is doing it (host IDS/IPS/Firewalls tend to intercept outbound connections to port 25/TCP).

Or you could just avoid all the above and run the test from a different machine in a different network :)

Comment: with which program can I make these network captures?

Comment: tcpdump or wireshark are usually the favourites of the crowd :)